# Trying to retrieve xml data with taxii

Tags: xml

I am new to the taxii structure, and I am having difficulty finding a proper taxii tutorial or set of code examples online.  I've written a successful Discovery Request, but I am struggling with pulling more xml data off my target site.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials or repositories of examples for using taxii?  I think I just need a better foundation of the terminology and a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

The best source of this kind of information is still [TAXII 1.1 spec](https://taxiiproject.github.io/releases/1.1/).

If you're not interested in gritty details, you might want to use a higher level TAXII client library I wrote, [Cabby](https://cabby.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Cabby also provides CLI commands like `taxii-discovery`, `taxii-poll` and `taxii-push` (see the docs), so you can easily script TAXII calls.

You are also welcome to look into the Cabby's source code on Github to understand how it works under the hood.